# Is it possible to make a hard-edged gradient on a large element?

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

I ran into a problem using a `linear-gradient` on a particularly large element.

On smaller elements, a hard edge can be achieved with the following:

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #000, #000 33%, #0f0 0);
```

However when the element has a very large height, the edge is soft. You can see in the following image and example below, the second version has a soft edge when the element is very large and the same gradient is applied.

[image: hard and soft edged gradients]

I have tried many variations on the linear gradient and have been unable to achieve a hard edge on the large version. Is there a way to apply a gradient with a hard edge on a large element?

HTML example:

```css
div {
  height: 5000px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #000, #000 20px, #0f0 0);
}
div:first-child {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

### Edit

The goal of this gradient is for use with another background image, so I prefer techniques that are compatible with the following (don't cover the image):

```css
div {
  height: 5000px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/600x20), linear-gradient(180deg, #000, #000 20px, #0f0 0);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

### Edit 2

Thanks to @Tarun, this appears to be browser related. The above image is a screenshot from Chromium 45. Safari and Firefox appear to render correctly.

### Edit 3

There is an open [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543625) for chromium about this issue.

Comment: As you mentioned in the chromium bug, I already asked this before - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151371/solid-gradients-not-really-solid-dont-have-crisp-edges-at-color-stops/... BTW happens on mobile chrome as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've found an alternative using gradients to achieve the same effect, however I think it should be possible to achieve this with 1 gradient, so I consider this a work-around.

The trick is to use multiple backgrounds with 2 gradients that don't change color. Then just define `background-size` to achieve the hard edge effect. See the working snippet:

```css
div {
  height: 5000px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000, #000), linear-gradient(#0f0, #0f0);
  background-size: 100% 20px, 100%;
}
div:first-child {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: How did this answer get a downvote? It's not optimal, but certainly a solution

Comment: Indeed, that's a great alternative that ensures that the gradient retains a hard edge. Here's another quick example I created: https://codepen.io/16kbit/pen/prvZVe

Comment: is there a way to use this solution with a direction like 'to top right'?

Answer (score 10):

This works for me.

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0% ,black 20% ,green 20% ,green 100%);
```

**edit:** I've tried to do exactly what you're doing in the question, and I'm getting a hard edge on both boxes. Your problem must be related to your browser.

**edit 2:** confirmed
[image: comparison]

Comment: There still isn't a hard edge

Comment: That is not a hard edge. There is a transition in there

Comment: The edge is not hard, it's still soft. Try it with a large enough element.

Comment: How large? I'm using a height of 10000 pixels and there still is very much a hard edge.

Comment: I don't know how rendering of SO snippets works, but this may be browser related. I'm using Chromium 45. I copy/pasted your code into my question and the edge is soft.

Comment: The problem appears to be with Chrome then (see edit)

Comment: Looks like it, the other browser is safari?

Answer (score 7):

You could use box shadow for the same effect.

```css
div {
  height: 5000px;
}
div {
  background: #0f0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 100px 0 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is pretty clever, although definitely still a work-around. It's also not helpful for my particular use case, as it covers up other background images (see update in question).

Answer (score 4):

You need to repeat each color, and each percent rate of `linear-gradient` in a tricky, but expressive way. Let's see it in a six colors sample to understand the principle.
This approach works for any size of block.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-image:
      linear-gradient(90deg,
                       red,
                       red     17%,
                       orange  17%, 
                       orange  34%, 
                       yellow  34%,
                       yellow  51%,
                       black   51%,
                       black   68%,
                       green   68%,
                       green   85%,
                       blue    85%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is informative, but it ignores the discussion. The gradients in the original question achieve the effect perfectly on browsers without a bug. If you open the [original snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233989/is-it-possible-to-make-a-hard-edged-gradient-on-a-large-element/56730416#56730416) I suspect you'll see it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bit more codespace and set up your gardient like following:

```
background: #4c4c4c;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #4c4c4c 0%,#2c2c2c 50%,#000000 51%,#131313 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#131313',GradientType=0 );
```

The solid background setting is there to make sure your page is showing some color if the browser somehow fails to support this type of gardient or its filter.

It is also preferred to include -moz, -o and other browser-based fixups to make sure.

Comment: Never mind, I just noticed the other answer that was implementing this exactly same solution and didn't fix it. Aaron's answer however is something I've faced before on my behalf too, that just didn't come up on my mind.

Answer (score 0):

This creates a gradient with a sharp edge.
The fractional digits are forcing the browser to render high fidelity edge.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(229,159,0,1) 0%, rgba(229,159,0,1) 49.99%, rgba(130,163,0,1) 50%, rgba(130,163,0,1) 100%);
```